# $S=\{0,1,2,3\}$. Show that $(S,+)$ is a Semi group where $+$ defines addition Modulo 4

Tags: education

I have search out my whole maths book for it..but didn't got this question in my book and I need to learn it for my exam..So if you people can please solve this for me?

> $S=\{0,1,2,3\}$. Show that $(S,+)$ is a Semi group where $+$ defines addition Modulo 4?

Waiting for your reply please..

Comment: What have you tried? There is no trick here, just applying the definitions. Which of the properties of a semigroup were you not able to show?

Comment: I have tried nothing so far..as I am not even sure of this question..that's why I asked you people to solve it..so that I can understand please..that how it is solved..

Comment: Do you know what a semigroup is?

Comment: If you have not tried anything, then seeing us solve it will be unlikely to lead to you really understanding how to do the problem.

Comment: Having some problems in fully understanding it...

Comment: Ok, which part of it? Do you know the definition of a semigroup? Do you know what addition modulo $4$ means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short a semigroup is a set $S$ together with some binary operation
$\star$ on it that is **associative**. That means that for every pair
of elements $x,y\in S$ there is an element $x\star y\in S$ and the
rule $\left(x\star y\right)\star z=x\star\left(y\star z\right)$ is obeyed.
An example is $\mathbb{N}=\left\{ 1,2,\dots\right\} $ together with
the addition as operation, denoted by $+$. It is a semigroup since
rule $\left(n+m\right)+k=n+\left(m+k\right)$ is satisfied. In your
case we deal with $S=\left\{ 0,1,2,3\right\} $ and the operation
is addition modulo $4$. To show that it is a semigroup it must be
verified that the rule of associativity is valid in this situation. That is what you are asked to do.

Caution: check whether this definition of semigroup agrees with the one
in your book. It can be that it is also demanded that $S$ contains some specific
element $e$ having the property that $e\star s=s\star e=s$ for
each $s\in S$. I would speak of a 'monoid' instead of a semigroup, but others don't. If that is the case
then the mentioned example $\mathbb{N}=\left\{ 1,2,\dots\right\} $ with addition
should be replaced by $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ and
$0$ is the specific element (called identity or unit).

Comment: Thanks...@drhab for explaining this to me...but I am not sure....as normally just as you said the rule is (x⋆y)⋆z=x⋆(y⋆z) and they are asking something very different...so in simple case what can be the solution of this question just in short..?

Comment: Then what *very different* (and different *from what*?) are they asking??? That does not come forward in your question or comments. It is simply enough to say: For integers $n,m,k$ we have $\left(n+m\right)+k=n+\left(m+k\right)$
and consequently $\left(n+m\right)+k\equiv n+\left(m+k\right)$ mod
$4$. This proves that $S=\left\{ 0,1,2,3\right\} $ equipped with
addition mod $4$ is a semigroup.

Comment: So should I write the answer to them in this way as? :  For integers n,m,k we have (n+m)+k=n+(m+k) and consequently (n+m)+k≡n+(m+k) mod 4. This proves that S={0,1,2,3} equipped with addition mod 4 is a semigroup

Comment: If I would have asked you the question and you should have given this answer then I would be completely satisfied. Did you check about what I wrote in my answer under the word 'caution'?

Comment: Yeah..sure...the problem is that this question is not in my book..may be seems as the course got changed last year..so this question is may be from old book..but I am not sure...